# Generic hashtable in C

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to create a generic hash table in C. I've read a few different implementations, and came across a couple of different approaches.

The first is to use macros like this: http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h.html

And the second is to use a struct with 2 void pointers like this:

```
struct hashmap_entry
{
    void *key;
    void *value;
};
```

From what I can tell this approach isn't great because it means that each entry in the map requires at least 2 allocations: one for the key and one for the value, regardless of the data types being stored. (Is that right???)

I haven't been able to find a decent way of keeping it generic without going the macro route. Does anyone have any tips or examples that might help me out?

Comment: Macros are a mechanism for repeating *code*.  They are not data structures.  It is unlikely that you can implement a general-purpose hash table without relying on some kind of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Additionally, that a data structure contains pointers says nothing whatever about dynamic allocation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your first point makes sense. If you take a look at the link I posted you'll see what I meant by that. Re: pointers...I meant that since it contains pointers, if you try to add an item to the map without dynamic allocation it will be invalid if you attempt to use that map outside the function those items are in, correct?

Comment: Well, it's possible but not without limitation and a lot of tricks.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks a lot! That's what I thought, but being relatively new to C I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious that someone could point out to me. Cheers!

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is my assumption about pointers in the previous comment correct?

Comment: @blackspirerider Possible don't mean that I will recommend it. C is not design to do that. You will have overhead and a lot of bug issue. Maybe you should try to do a generic linked list before try this.

Comment: @blackspirerider, the need for dynamic allocation, if it exists, follows from how you intend to use the hash table.  It does not derive from whether the data structure with which you implement the hash table contains pointers.

Comment: @blackspirerider, you are correct, however, that automatic variables do not survive the return of the function call in which they are declared.  If you want an object that can do so then it must be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Overall, my point is that what you present as two different approaches are non-apposite.  Very likely, your example pointer-based implementation uses a data structure containing pointers, similar to the one you present as an alternative.  You just don't manipulate it directly in that case.  You might even find that the macros perform dynamic memory management.  You're comparing apples and architecture.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks a lot for taking the time to explain that! I see where my assumptions started to break down.

Comment: Consider taking a look at the glib hash table.  It's there for the taking. https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/ghash.c

Comment: A *generic* hashtable in C is a bad idea. The *neat* implementation will require function pointers, which are slow, since these functions cannot be inlined. To allow inlining of functions you'll either have to write the code manually, or use a code generator, or macros. Which can get messy.

Answer (score 2):

C does not provide what you need directly, nevertheless you may want to do something like this:

Imagine that your hash table is a fixed size array of double linked lists and it is OK that items are always allocated/destroyed on the application layer. These conditions will not work for every case, but in many cases they will. Then you will have these data structures and sketches of functions and protototypes:

```
struct HashItemCore
{
    HashItemCore  *m_prev;
    HashItemCore  *m_next;
};

struct HashTable
{
    HashItemCore  m_data[256];    // This is actually array of circled
                                  // double linked lists.
    int     (*GetHashValue)(HashItemCore *item);
    bool    (*CompareItems)(HashItemCore *item1, HashItemCore *item2);
    void    (*ReleaseItem)(HashItemCore *item);
};

void  InitHash(HashTable *table)
{
    // Ensure that user provided the callbacks.
    assert(table->GetHashValue != NULL && table->CompareItems != NULL && table->ReleaseItem != NULL);

    // Init all double linked lists. Pointers of empty list should point to themselves.
    for (int i=0; i<256; ++i)
       table->m_data.m_prev = table->m_data.m_next = table->m_data+i;
}

void  AddToHash(HashTable *table, void *item);
void *GetFromHash(HashTable *table, void *item);
....
void *ClearHash(HashTable *table);
```

In these functions you need to implement the logic of the hash table. While working they will be calling user defined callbacks to find out the index of the slot and if items are identical or not.

The users of this table should define their own structures and callback functions for every pair of types that they want to use:

```
struct HashItemK1V1
{
     HashItemCore m_core;
     K1 key;
     V1 value;
};

int CalcHashK1V1(void *p)
{
     HashItemK1V1 *param  = (HashItemK1V1*)p;
     // App code.
}

bool CompareK1V1(void *p1, void *p2)
{
     HashItemK1V1 *param1  = (HashItemK1V1*)p1;
     HashItemK1V1 *param2  = (HashItemK1V1*)p2;
     // App code.
}

void FreeK1V1(void *p)
{
     HashItemK1V1 *param  = (HashItemK1V1*)p;
     // App code if needed.
     free(p);
}
```

This approach will not provide type safety because items will be passed around as  void pointers assuming that every application structure starts with `HashItemCore` member. This will be sort of hand made polymorphysm. This is maybe not perfect, but this will work.

I implemented this approach in C++ using templates. But if you will strip out all fancies of C++, in the nutshell it will be exactly what I described above. I used my table in multiple projects and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 2):

A generic hashtable in C is a bad idea.

- a *neat* implementation will require function pointers, which are slow, since these functions cannot be inlined (the general case will need at least two function calls *per hop*: one to compute the hash value and one for the final compare)
- to allow inlining of functions you'll either have to

  - write the code manually
  - or use a code generator
  - or macros. Which can get messy

IIRC, the linux kernel uses macros to create and maintain (some of?) its hashtables.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have generic data types, so what you want to do (no extra allocations and no `void*` casting) is not really possible. You can use macros to generate the right data functions/structs on the fly, but you're trying to avoid macros as well.

So you need to give up at least one of your ideas.

You could have a generic data structure without extra allocations by allocating something like:

```
size_t key_len;
size_t val_len;
char key[];
char val[];
```

in one go and then handing out either void pointers, or adding an api for each specific type.

Alternatively, if you have a limited number of types you need to handle, you could also tag the value with the right one so now each entry contains:

```
size_t key_len;
size_t val_len;
int val_type;
char key[];
char val[];
```

but in the API at least you can verify that the requested type is the right one.

Otherwise, to make everything generic, you're left with either macros, or changing the language.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  Are your examples supposed to be presenting members of a struct?  If so, they don't work.

Comment: That's why I didn't put them in a `struct` :) You can't define the struct this way, since the lengths of fields are not known at compile time. (because C doesn't have generic types!) You can fake it though by allocating the right size yourself and filling out the fields manually. You can also help yourself by making only the lengths a struct and casting the beginning of the allocated memory to that struct.

Comment: Well, C structs can have flexible array members (at most one each), so your assertion is not quite correct.  But in any case, now I'm *sure* I don't follow what you're actually suggesting, or how it serves the OP's objective better than the alternatives he presented.